# How to defaultly return image.url when we get model Object?

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I want my model object to always return the `image.url` of field image.

My model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want something like:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_avatar(self): # some default func for returning fields
        return self.avatar.url
```

It have to work like this, When I get the object:

```
content = Content.objects.get(pk=1)
print(content.avatar)
```

And it should print the path:

```
/media/uploads/dsadsadsa.jpg
```

Briefly, I want something that will change the return of model field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a property to your model like this, notice I added an underscore to the field name:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    ...
    _avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def avatar(self):
        return self._avatar.url
```

Now you can do:

```
print(content.avatar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`__str__()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#str) method

```
class Content(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return self.avatar.url
        except AttributeError: # "self.avatar" may be None
            return "no avatar"
```

### UPDATE-1

I think, the **`@propert`** may suite you

```
class Content(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=file, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def avatar_url(self):
        try:
            return self.avatar.url
        except AttributeError:  # "self.avatar" may be None
            return "no avatar"
```

Now, you could access the url as,
**`print(content.avatar_url)`**

Comment: It will return url when I do: `print(content)`, not: `print(content.avatar)`

Comment: I want my model not to return ImageField, it have to return only its url

Comment: When you run `print(content)`, its calling the `__str__()` fucntion